# Why isn't Tefilat Mussaf consistent?

Tags: tefilla, chagim-holidays, musaf, nusach-edot-hammizrach

According to Nusach Edot HamMizrach, why does the Mussaf prayer on Shabbat and Rosh Chodesh include a description of the actual mussaf sacrifice, while the Mussaf prayer on Moed does not? Why aren't they consistent with each other?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10839/37), which cites some sources about the distinction between Shabbos and Yamim Tovim in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed by the Tur in [Orach Chaim 591](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Orach_Chaim.591.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). After quoting the opinion of Rabbeinu Tam, that the verses describing the sacrifices must be recited, he writes:

> ושאר המפרשים לא פירשו כן, אלא שיוצא ידי המוספין במה שאומר ככתוב בתורתך וכו' ... **וכן נוהגין בספרד שאין אומרים פסוקי הקרבנות אלא בשבת ור"ח דרגילי בהו ולא אתי למטעי, אבל בשאר מועדים דלא רגילי בהו אתו למטעי לכך אין מזכיר אותם**
>
> The other commentaries did not explain so. Rather, one fulfills his obligation of *musaf* through reciting the phrase "as is written in Your Torah" etc. [without reciting the verses themselves] ... **And this is the custom in Spain, not to say the verses of sacrifices, apart from on Shabbat and Rosh Chodesh where they are used to them and will not make mistakes. However, on other festivals they are not used to them and will make mistakes, therefore one does not mention them.**