# Why can we recite Tikanta shabbos in musaf shabbos amidah without reading Parshas Tamid?

Tags: shabbat, musaf, maseches-tamid

If one doesn't recite Parshas hatamid before Shacharis on Shabbos for whatever reason, how is it still permissible to recite Musaf Shabbos Tikanta Shabbos which describes the musaf offering ? Without reciting Parshas Tamid at start wouldn't that prevent the recital of Tikanta Shabbos since its an addition to Tamid?

Comment: Even without reciting parshas tamid, shacharis is a replacement for Korban tamid, so maybe that's enough to make it not be problematic.

Comment: @ Lo ani That makes sense. I just thought because we recite the description of Musaf in Tikanta shabbos, it felt weird and off because one wouldn't have read the description of Tamid prior. Ashaynem dank.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38476/759