# Musaf korban for second day Sukkos outside Israel

Tags: sukkot, musaf, golus-exile

In our observance of second day Yom Tov when we continue the minhag of our forefathers even though we now have a fixed calendar and know very well which day it is. [Gem Beitzah 4b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%94_%D7%93_%D7%91#fn_%D7%97_back).

The result is that in the musaf service for the second day of Sukkos outside of Israel, the musaf offering mentioned is the same as on the first day.

So we stand before Hashem and effectively say something like, “We are unable to bring the korban musaf for today. We should bring the korban for the second day of Sukkos, but Your sages taught us to treat this day like a sofeik first day and so we are only going to mention the korban for day one even though we know very well that today is the second day of the chag.”

I have been told that if we were to mention the offerings for both the first and second days, then we would be denigrating the holiness of the second day.

My question is whether there have been any proposals within Orthodox Judaism to mention the true musaf korban for the second day of Sukkos in golus.

Comment: Consider the end of Tur 662

Comment: Note the situation isn't as bad as you indicate since reciting the specific verses is not strictly required. You still say ואת מוסף יום חג הסוכות הזה נעשה ונקריב לפניך כמו שכתבת בתורתך and that's true and sufficient.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's good. How do you know it?

Comment: look in a Sefardi machzor. They generally skip the verses lechatchila. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15679/759 It is probably a machloket rishonim as is anything, but still it's a major consideration here to not be sooo worried.

Comment: Thank you -this does sound like the answer to my problem.

Comment: On the other hand one could argue that saying the wrong verses is worse than saying no verses

Comment: The same issue comes up on the first day of shemini atzeres and there you're not even saying the right holiday @doubleaa

Comment: @Heshy except there you're missing the fake day. Here you're skipping the real day which is arguably more troubling.