# Saying the pesukim of the musaf instead of the correct nusach

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, musaf

In the musaf shemoneh esrei on Rosh Chodesh, Yom Tov, or Chol Hamoed, if you accidentally continue with the pesukim from Pinchas instead of saying ומנחתם ונסכיהם כמדובר, should you go back:

- if you are still in the bracha?
- after you finish the bracha?
- after shemoneh esrei?

I can think of 3 subcategories.  I can imagine that one or both of the last 2 might be treated differently than the first, since in those cases by deviating from the nusach you are omitting some details.

- Rosh Chodesh, Pesach, Shavuot, Yom Kippur, and the first day(s) of Sukkot: the nusach of ומנחתם ונסכיהם כמדובר doesn't add any additional information that isn't in the pesukim, but we are still supposed to say the standard text.
- Rosh Hashana - My nusach says ושני שעירים לכפר, obliquely mentioning the chatat of Rosh Chodesh, while the pesukim only mention עולת החדש ומנחתו.  (If I'm remembering correctly some nuschaot only say ושעיר לכפר, in which case Rosh Hashana goes back into category 1.)
- Chol Hamoed Sukkos and Shemini Atzeret - ומנחתם ונסכיהם כמדובר gives the size of the menachot, the pesukim don't.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10839/759

Comment: Some Nuschaot have 2 Chatat offerings on Shavout too.

Comment: Rashi says that you only have to say תמידים כסדרם ומוספים כהלכתם to be Yotzei.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot I figured the answer if you already finished the bracha was going to be no, I just added that for completeness.  The primary question is what to do if you're still in the bracha.  Is there any purpose going back?  For times other than Rosh Hashana, Chol Hamoed Sukkot, and Shemini Atzeret, you don't add anything by going back, but maybe you should anyway.